# Qt - How to change the size of QRadiobutton while the size of window is changing

Tags: c++, css, qt

I was trying to let the size of `QRadioButton` change with the size of window. What I need is that when I am adjusting the size of the window to become bigger (or smaller), the `QRadioButton` should also adjust to become bigger (or smaller).

I tried to use the method which I used for `QPushButton`, but I found that it doesn't work (check pic1 and pic2 at the bottom). The size of `QRadioButton` just stays the same.

Besides, I've also tried `setStyleSheet` for the `QRadioButton`, but then I clicking on the picture is invalid, that is not the result I want (clicking on the picture should be valid in my case).
I would like to know how I should modify my code. Thanks!

Here are some of the related code:

.h file

```
QRadioButton *funcSourceOrientedButton;
QPushButton *funcLockButton;
```

.cpp file

```
QPixmap pixmap(":/images/Function/SourceOriented.png");
QIcon ButtonIcon(pixmap);
funcSourceOrientedButton->setIcon(ButtonIcon);
funcSourceOrientedButton->setIconSize(function_oriented_button_size);
funcSourceOrientedButton->setMinimumSize(function_oriented_button_size);
funcSourceOrientedButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

funcLockButton->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/images/Function/WLock.png);");
funcLockButton->setMinimumSize(function_button_size);
funcLockButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

Here are the pics:

pic1

[image]

pic2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a layout and add those buttons to it

mywidget.h

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QRadioButton;
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

private:
    QSize __CalculateIndicatorSize(const QSize & radioBtnSize);
private:
    QRadioButton * m_radioBtn1;
    QRadioButton * m_radioBtn2;

    QString styleForButton_;
    QString styleForIndicator_;
};

#endif // MYWIDGET_H
```

mywidget.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QEvent>
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    styleForButton_ = "QRadioButton{border-width: 10 10 10 10; border-image: url(C:/Users/phamat/Desktop/bg.png) 10 10 10 10;}";
    styleForIndicator_ = "QRadioButton::indicator{width: %1px; height: %2px;}";

    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
    layout->setSpacing(20);
    setLayout(layout);

    m_radioBtn1 = new QRadioButton(this);
    m_radioBtn1->setText("Radio button 1");
    m_radioBtn1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    m_radioBtn1->setStyleSheet(styleForButton_);
    m_radioBtn1->installEventFilter(this);
    layout->addWidget(m_radioBtn1);

    m_radioBtn2 = new QRadioButton(this);
    m_radioBtn2->setText("Radio button 2");
    m_radioBtn2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    m_radioBtn2->setStyleSheet(styleForButton_);
    m_radioBtn2->installEventFilter(this);
    layout->addWidget(m_radioBtn2);
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
}

bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == m_radioBtn1)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
        {
            QSize size = __CalculateIndicatorSize(m_radioBtn1->size());
            m_radioBtn1->setStyleSheet(styleForButton_ + styleForIndicator_.arg(size.width()).arg(size.height()));
        }
    }
    else if (obj == m_radioBtn2)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
        {
            QSize size = __CalculateIndicatorSize(m_radioBtn2->size());
            m_radioBtn2->setStyleSheet(styleForButton_ + styleForIndicator_.arg(size.width()).arg(size.height()));
        }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}


QSize MyWidget::__CalculateIndicatorSize(const QSize & radioBtnSize)
{
    if (radioBtnSize.width() > 300)
    {
        return QSize(20, 20);
    }
    else if (radioBtnSize.width() > 200)
    {
        return QSize(15, 15);
    }
    else
    {
        return QSize(10, 10);
    }
}
```

pic 1

[image]

pic 2

[image]

Comment: The OP refers to a QRadioButton.

Comment: Updated the code. I added stylesheet for QRadioButton for easily noticing size change

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain well. I mean the whole picture(including the text), not only the frame. I've edited the problem again.
Besides, I've added layout in my code, but it seems that this doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @Gary I don't see any layout in the code provided in the question

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn It seems that you code is closer to what I want. But in this case, the little indicator dot button still can't change its size with the button picture, and it overlaps with the button picture. Is it possible to separate the indicator from the button picture and also able changing its size?
here are the results image I tried:
     [link1](http://imgur.com/fs7R7cM)
     [link2](http://imgur.com/OwRaV3L)

Comment: The indicator has size itself and the size doesnot change when the button's size changes. You need change indicator size manually. I updated the code, hope that help.

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn I tried to use the code, but it just shows the error: '__super' has not been declared.

Comment: Sorry, i am using vc++. You can change __super to QWidget (QWidget::eventFilter)